# How to remove ingress annotation using Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

In the Base Ingress file I have added the following annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet` and it needs to be removed in one of the environment.

Base Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: test
```

I created a ingress-patch.yml in overlays and added the below

```
- op: remove
  path: /metadata/annotations/nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet
```

But it gives the below error when executing Kustomize Build

```
Error: remove operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/metadata/annotations/nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet": missing value
```

Answer (score 8):

The path `/metadata/annotations/nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet` doesn't work because `/` is the character that JSONPath uses to separate elements in the document; there's no way for a JSONPath parser to know that the `/` in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet` means something different from the `/` in `/metadata/annotations`.

The [JSON Pointer RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) (which is the syntax used to specify the `path` component of a patch) tells us that we need to escape `/` characters using `~1`. If we have the following in `ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    example-annotation: foo
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: test
```

And write our `kustomization.yaml` like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ingress.yaml

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Ingress
      name: ingress
    patch: |
      - op: remove
        path: /metadata/annotations/nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io~1auth-snippet
```

Then the output of `kustomize build` is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    example-annotation: foo
  name: ingress
```